# Убрать оступы по бокам editText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, design

Когда я создаю editText вот таким способом:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/enter_your_email"
    android:id="@+id/email_edit_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:hint="@string/email" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Нигде я не указываю оступы, но вот тут они появляются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего отступы прописаны у вас в одном из родителей выше по иерархии

Comment: @Jarvis_J Да, действительно, у меня там padding прописан в главном layout. Но он применяется для всех, а этот edittext уезжает чуть дальше, и я думаю, что это особенность этого элемента, но хотелось бы это поменять

Comment: @Jarvis_J Наверное, нужно будет создавать background для editText?

Comment: можете попробовать поставить в `TextInputLayout` отрицательный `margin`, равный `padding` родителей :) Бэк в этом случае не сильно поможет.

Comment: @Jarvis_J Это действительно работает, но не является ли это говнокодом?

Comment: Может быть есть варианты лучше. Я их не знаю)

Comment: @Jarvis_J В любом случае это помогло, так что напиши ответ, я его приму

Comment: Это быстрый хак =) Но нигде не видел других решений для выравнивания `TextInputLayout`, кроме как установить значение `android:layout_marginLeft` равном **"-4dp"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте в `TextInputLayout` атрибуты с отрицательным `margin` равным `padding` родителя.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-parentPadding"
android:layout_marginRight="-parentPadding"
```